# Value PrimeFaces p:selectBooleanCheckbox is unchecked in dataGrid

Tags: java, primefaces, datagrid, primefaces-mobile, selectbooleancheckbox

When I change selectBooleanCheckbox from java.sun.com/jsf/html

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{model.items}" var="item">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
    id="test-h"
    value="#{item.use}">
    <h:outputText value="use" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:dataGrid>
```

to PrimeFaces selectBooleanCheckbox

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{model.items}" var="item">
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
     id="test-p"
     value="#{item.use}"
     itemLabel="use">
  </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:dataGrid>
```

value from bean is not used.

There is always value false for p:selectBooleanCheckbox. It doesn't matter what item.use value is.

**EDIT:** I added Model. It's very simple:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Model implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7681870663928901842L;

    private List<ScannedItem> items;

    public List<ScannedItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ScannedItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

and entity ScannedItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scanned_item")
public class ScannedItem implements Serializable {

//...

    @Column(name = "in_use")
    private boolean use;

    public boolean isUse() {
        return use;
    }

    public void setUse(boolean use) {
        this.use = use;
    }

//...

}
```

**Note**: I am using *primefaces mobile* from *primefaces 5.1.1*

Comment: post your managed bean code

Comment: I added it to my question. Thanks.